# Remover botão do form e remover o codigo

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Boa tarde pessoal, como posso limpar o codigo na situação onde, coloquei os botões conforme um determinado uso, depois resolvemos tirar os botões mas os codigos estão lá, ( os eventos click )
Como posso remover o botão e remover os eventos e referencias sem detonar o programa ?

Comment: Não é só apagar o código do evento?

Comment: Fiz uma vez e me dei mal, não quero arriscar novamente

Comment: Não tem porquê dar errado, é só remover o controle e depois o código.

Comment: Até então funcionou sem problemas

Comment: Isso é `Forms` ou `Web`? Procure os eventos no código pelo nome (*Button1_Click* por exemplo), porque os eventos podem ser registrados em outro local e dar erro se você remover só o método em si

Comment: Num `WindowsForm`, os eventos são registrados no arquivo `.Designer.cs`, se for um `WebForms` antigo, no método `InitializeComponent`, e assim por diante, então não adianta só remover do código, tem que limpar nesses locais também

Comment: @RicardoPontual é WindowsForm

Comment: Então procure os eventos no arquivo com o mesmo nome do form com `.Designer.cs`, senão vai dar erro se você remover só do arquivo `.cs`

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente o erro deve esse após a exclusão:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso acontece que ao click 2 vezes no controle para criar um evento ele vincula o evento no Form1.Designer.cs, dai se vc simplesmente apagar o evento no código ele gere esse erro.

Soluções:

1º Removendo a partir dos eventos disponíveis listados na aba Ferramentas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2ºRemovendo direto em Form1.Design.cs
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado!!!

Comment: Eu removi o botão e o evento tambem, está funcionando aqui tranquilo

Comment: blz!!!! Se ajudou, click na setinha sinalizando que a resposta foi útil.